# Equivalence relation using tableaux

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can I prove that two formulae are equivalent using [analytic tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux)? For example, how can I prove the following theorem?
$$ (p \rightarrow q) \equiv (\neg q \rightarrow \neg p)$$

Comment: I imagine you mean $\neg q\rightarrow \neg p$?

Comment: I wrote wrong the equivalence,edited.

Comment: Do you know how to handle $\lnot$ and $\to$ in a tableau proof, and you are only looking for how to deal with $\equiv$?  Or are you confused by tableau proofs in general?

Comment: tableau proofs in general. I don't know how relate the equivalence with tableau.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In using tableaux (I've also heard them called truth-trees (as opposed to truth tables)) to prove a sentence $\phi$, we can start with $\lnot\phi$ and show that every branch (a potential way of satisfying $\lnot\phi$) leads to a contradiction.  If every potential way of satisfying $\lnot\phi$ is a contradiction, then $\phi$ must be true.

I'd suggest that in using the tableaux for equivalences, you replace $\phi \equiv \psi$ with $(\phi \to \psi) \land (\psi \to \phi)$.  I'd also suggest that you allow two “shortcuts” for convenience.  The first is that a conditional $\phi \to \psi$ is equivalent to the disjunction $\lnot\phi \lor \psi$, so when a branch has $\phi \to\psi$, it can split with $\lnot\phi$ on one side, and $\psi$ on the other.  The second shortcut is that a negated conditional $\lnot(\phi\to\psi)$ is logically equivalent to $\phi \land \lnot\psi$, and this can be expanded in place, too.  I will also presume that we can move between $\lnot\lnot\phi$ and $\phi$ without making note of it. Using these shortcuts, we can construct a tree for your formula.  This isn't quite the tree presentation that is usually shown (because I don't know how to render that in MathJax), but it should be close enough that you can see the structure.

$$\frac{
\begin{array}{c}
 \lnot[ (p \to q) \equiv (\lnot q \to \lnot p) ] \\
 \lnot[ ((p \to q) \to (\lnot q \to \lnot p)) \land ((\lnot q \to \lnot p) \to (p \to q))] \\
\lnot((p \to q) \to (\lnot q \to \lnot p)) \lor \lnot((\lnot q \to \lnot p) \to (p \to q)) \end{array}
}{\displaystyle
\frac{
\begin{array}{c}
\lnot((p \to q) \to (\lnot q \to \lnot p)) \\
\lnot(\lnot q \to \lnot p) \\
\lnot q \\
p \\
p \to q
\end{array}}{
\begin{array}{c}
\lnot p \\
\bot
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{c}
q \\
\bot \\
\end{array}}
\qquad
\frac{
\begin{array}{c}
\lnot((\lnot q \to \lnot p) \to (p \to q)) \\
\lnot(p \to q) \\
p \\
\lnot q \\
\lnot q \to \lnot p
\end{array}
}{
\begin{array}{c}
q \\
\bot
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{c}
\lnot p \\
\bot
\end{array}
}
}
$$

Since all the branches terminate, $\lnot[ (p \to q) \equiv (\lnot q \to \lnot p) ]$ is unsatisfiable, which means that the following sentence is a theorem.

$$(p \to q) \equiv (\lnot q \to \lnot p)$$

If that notation isn't quite clear, here's a more linear presentation that might help.

1. $\lnot[ (p \to q) \equiv (\lnot q \to \lnot p) ]$
2. $\lnot[ ((p \to q) \to (\lnot q \to \lnot p)) \land ((\lnot q \to \lnot p) \to (p \to q))]$
3. $\lnot((p \to q) \to (\lnot q \to \lnot p)) \lor \lnot((\lnot q \to \lnot p) \to (p \to q))$
4. - Branch for $\lnot((p \to q) \to (\lnot q \to \lnot p))$ from 3.
5. - $(p \to q)$
6. - $\lnot(\lnot q \to \lnot p)$
7. - $\lnot q$
8. - $p$
9. - - Branch for $\lnot p$ from 5.
10. - - $\bot$ from $p, \lnot p$, end branch
11. - - Branch for $q$ from 5.
12. - - $\bot$ from $q, \lnot q$, end branch
13. - Branch for $\lnot((\lnot q \to \lnot p) \to (p \to q))$ from 3.
14. - $\lnot q \to \lnot p$
15. - $\lnot(p \to q)$
16. - $p$
17. - $\lnot q$
18. - - Branch for $q$ from 14.
19. - - $\bot$ from $q, \lnot q$, end branch
20. - - Branch for $\lnot p$ from 14.
21. - - $\bot$ from $p, \lnot p$, end branch

Answer (score 1):

Your class probably defines 
$A\equiv B$ as  $(A\to B)\land (B\to A)$, so you can treat it that way for the tableau.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? I don't understand what you want.

[image]

Comment: You used Truth Table to prove. I want to know how to prove the same thing using tableau (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux).