# Injectivity and Imdepotency implies Surjectivity

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-verification, predicate-logic

This question stem from   [Natural Deduction (FeedBack)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524446/natural-deduction-feedback/528367#528367). The reason why I think it is justifiable to open this up as a separate question is that I am now considering other measures to show it, possibly using the completeness theorem. As stated, my goal is to show:

> *Injectivity and idempotency implies surjectivity.*

[image]

As Peter pointed out, the **modus pones** step is invalid. However, I have great difficulties in finding a way to use the given information in such a way that I can show surjectivity, at least formally. I think I understand it, informally. The imdepotence property restricts (possibly shrinks) the range of the injective function so as it is of the same cardinality as the domain.

Answer (score 5):

The only injective idempotent function $f:X\to X$ is the identity function.  Proof: For any $x\in X$, idempotence gives us $f(f(x))=f(x)$.  Now apply injectivity (with $f(x)$ in the role of $y$) to infer that $f(x)=x$.

Comment: When you say "$f(x)$ in the role of $y$, do you mean that I should (can?) substitute $y$ for $f(x)$ in the derivation?

Comment: @user100561 No, I mean to substitute $f(x)$ for $y$ in the injectivity assumption.